# Cannot be resolved to a variable - JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am working with an Oracle Database using Java and an SQL library. I'm trying to calculate students whose averages are one standard deviation away from the mean, add a column to flag those students, and count how many students meet the criteria and add them to a new table. I am getting an error that says the "allAvgs" variable and "theSD" variable "cannot be resolved to a variable". The error happens in my if statement, but I have already instantiated those variables. Why do I get this error? Any help is appreciated.

```
try{
         Statement stOne, stTwo, stThree, stFour;
         String SelectAverage = "SELECT MEAN FROM STUDENTS";
          ResultSet rsOne = stOne.executeQuery(SelectAverage);

    String TotalAverage = "SELECT Avg(MEAN) AS averages FROM STUDENTS";
          ResultSet rsTwo = stTwo.executeQuery(TotalAverage);     

          String student_stan_dev = "SELECT STDEV(MEAN) AS standardDeviation FROM STUDENTS";
          ResultSet rsThree = stThree.executeQuery(student_stan_dev);

           int onesdMean = 1;


           //Loop Duration_Sec column
           while(rsOne.next()){

           //Convert values into float values
           float allAvgs = rsOne.getFloat("MEAN");
           float totalAvg = rsTwo.getFloat("averages"); 
           float StDev = rsThree.getFloat("standardDeviation");

           float theSD = allAvgs - (onesdMean * StDev);
           }

        String flaggedStudents = "ALTER TABLE STUDENTS ADD FlaggedStudents INT";
        ResultSet rsFour = stFour.executeUpdate(flaggedStudents);

           if(allAvgs >= theSD){
               String FlagHint = "INSERT INTO STUDENTS.FlaggedStudents VALUES('1')";
               st.executeUpdate(FlagHint);
           }

        String countInstances = "SELECT STUDENTS.NAME, STUDENTS.FlaggedStudents" +
                "COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENTS) AS cnt FROM STUDENTS";
           st.executeQuery(countInstances);


        st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentCount" +
        "(NAME INT , cnt INT)");

        String insertVals = String.format("INSERT INTO StudentCount" +
                "(NAME , cnt INT") +
                " VALUES ('%s','%s')");

        st.execute(insertVals);enter code here
```

Comment: You can't use `theSD` outside of the block in which you declared it. It's out of scope.

Comment: Thank you both for answering my question, it worked! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are declared inside the `while(){...}` loop and limited to the block scope of the `while()` loop . You need to declare them outside the loop to expand their scope.

```
// you need to declare the variables outside
while(rsOne.next()){
    // this defines a scope , anything declared here is invisible outside
    // this scope

     float allAvgs = rsOne.getFloat("MEAN");
     float totalAvg = rsTwo.getFloat("averages"); 
     float StDev = rsThree.getFloat("standardDeviation");
     float theSD = allAvgs - (onesdMean * StDev);
}
......
......
// compiler has no idea about allAvgs and theSD here
if(allAvgs >= theSD){
    String FlagHint = "INSERT INTO STUDENTS.FlaggedStudents VALUES('1')";
    st.executeUpdate(FlagHint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `theSD` inside of the `while` loop block.

```
//Loop Duration_Sec column
while(rsOne.next()){

    ...
    float theSD = allAvgs - (onesdMean * StDev);
}
```

But try to use it right after it.

```
...

if(allAvgs >= theSD){ // theSD doesn't exist in this scope
    String FlagHint = "INSERT INTO STUDENTS.FlaggedStudents VALUES('1')";
    st.executeUpdate(FlagHint);
}
```

It doesn't exist outside the scope of the `while` loop. You need to declare (and initialize) it (and all others you need) outside the while loop. **Consider what would happen if the `while` loop evaluated to `false` and didn't run.**